# Failed to access Logic app via APIM when restricting APIM IP in logic app

Tags: azure, ip-address, azure-logic-apps, ip-restrictions, apim

**Problem statement:**

I have a logic app which I have exposed via APIM[I want this way as this is my design approach] and I want to allow only specific inbound IP address(in my case APIM IP) to access my logic app.

I have restricted the IPs in apim as follows, and which is working as expected.

```
    <ip-filter action="allow">
        <address-range from="xx.xx.xx.x1" to="xx.xx.xx.x5" /> //currently this is of no use.
        <address>xx.xx.xx.xx</address> //my local machine ip.
    </ip-filter>
```

Now, I have allowed the specific ip(apim ip) in my logic app and hit the request from my local machine, logic app prompt me an error.
[image]

When I added my local machine's Ip in logic app then it works as expected.

So,I think What is the point of restricting the ips in APIM because I need to allow all the IPs in logic app as well?

could anyone please assist/elaborate me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: The point is that you can only call your logic app from APIM... This is the expected behavior from your description

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but I am getting above weird exception. 
if i white-lists only APIM IP then I am getting the above exception but when I whitelisted my local machine IP(from where i am shooting the request) then the no any exception occurs.
So what is causing this behavior?

Comment: are you sending the request trough APIM ????

Comment: @Thomas Yes!, h2tps://api.apim-base-url/env/functionality/manual/paths/invoke- this is my APIM url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have analyzed the issue and below is the finding.

Getting **Unauthorized** is because of not whitelisting the local machine IP from which I was exploring the logic app to see the requested content.

Everything else is working as expected.

[image]

hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure portal, access to your Logic App. Under Settings, select `Workflow settings`.

Under `Access control configuration` > `Allowed inbound IP addresses`, select `Specific IP ranges`.

[image]

Then you will receive a 401 Unauthorized status with postman and if we try from our APIM, we should get a 202 Accepted status.

For more details, you could refer to this article about [How to restrict incoming IP ranges for a Logic App to accept only APIM calls](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/how-to-expose-and-protect-logic-app-using-azure-apim-part-2).

Comment: I tried with the same article, but i am getting different error as stated above.